# How does things work between MODEM and PC on the RJ45 ethernet cable?

Tags: rf, modem, rj45

I am a newbie in electronic and i would like to ask why there is Transmitter and Receiver in the RJ45 cable connecting the MODEM and Computer? Which one goes first

From Modem --> Receiver Receive signal ---> Transmit to the PC? OR

From PC computer --> Transmit signal to Modem to fetch signal ---> Then receive back into the PC computer

Please enlighten me

Comment: I have no clue what you are realy asking. About a protocol sequence? Or something electrical? And RJ45 is commonly used for Ethernet signals, not for a (telephone line) modem.

Comment: What i am trying to ask is because i am confused with the present of TX and RX line in the cable. There are TX+ TX- and RX+ RX- in the RJ45 line cable from MODEM to PC. What is the purse of the TX and RX between the MODEM and the PC? what are they doing?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you are asking for Ethernet then the TX lines are sending data, RX lines are receiving data. Transmission is differential so each end has a (+) and (-) pin.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're taking about 100 Mbps Ethernet here, and by modem you mean a cable modem (not an old 56k modems, which probably wouldn't be connected to a computer with an RJ45 cable).

The TX pins are outputs and the RX pins are inputs. The TX pins on one end are connected to the RX pins on the other end. Data to be sent from the computer to the modem would go out of the TX pins on the computer, down the cable, and into the RX pins on the modem. Data to be sent from the modem to the computer would go out of the TX pins on the modem, down the cable, and into the RX pins on the computer. The signals themselves are sent differentially, so whatever is sent on TX+ is sent inverted on TX-, and the receiver looks at the difference between RX+ and RX-.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl0xoE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes thats what i am talking about and not the old 56k modem. What i am trying to say is that i am confused why the RJ45 cable connected between modem and computer have the Transmitter and Receiver wire inside.

The whole thing is like this Phone Line (LAN Line) connected to the modem to supply internet signal then there is RJ45 cable that connect between modem and computer.

How the TX and RX communicate between modem and computer 

From MODEM to Computer ---> TX transmit signal and computer receive signal?

Comment: Is it like this?

MODEM --> TX cable --> Transmit signal to computer?
Computer -->Rx cable -->Modem receive signal from computer?

Comment: Does the schematic clear things up at all?

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for thank you very much...but i have a question in there let say left is modem and computer is right...why does the computer on the right need to transmit back to the modem? In my thought only the modem will need to transmit to the computer and receive by the computer? kindly advise

Comment: If the computer can't send anything, how do you request what web page to view? The communication is two way, so both have transmitters and receivers.

Comment: Now my understand is complete....you are perfect and thanks a gazillion...i thought the website is process inside the PC not in the modem lol ....

Comment: Well, the website isn't in the modem either, it's somewhere out on the internet, but the request has to go from your computer, through the modem, out over the internet to the server that hosts the site, and then the server sends the page back to you through the internet, then the modem, then to your computer.

Comment: You have answered me completely...and i liked very much ...thanks for all your effort

Answer (score 0):

The modem connects to the outside world either phone (DSL), cable (cable) or fiber.  The inside is ethernet either 100BaseT or 1000BaseT (10/100/1000).  That is an ethernet cable, two pair go one way two pair go the other, with 100baseT the rx/tx definition is fixed, for 1000, they can autonegotiate.  You should be able to connect the modem to a switch or router, latter being a very good idea, which has more of these RJ45 connectors/cables which you can then hook up wireless access points and/or computers.  going to see much better performance with a wired network connection than wireless, but most folks dont use desktop computers anymore so possibly never even need a wired ethernet connection as the modem is a router and access point (in part so the isp can use your modem to provide access for folks near by, xfinity mobile for example)

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet

what runs on the wired ethernet is the same as what runs wireless, just has a different transport down at the lower layers, like shipping the same piano but on a semi truck vs a train vs a boat, same payload different physical transport (wireless eventually lands on a wired network be it in your house or on the other end of what the modem is connected to, eventually has to, well I say wired it could be wire or fiber).

within the bits that go along these interfaces there are more layers, you see terms like TCP/IP,  well it has an ethernet or other outer layer, then an ip layer inside that then a tcp layer inside that then the payload which might be the text GET http://www.wikipedia.com or some such thing.  Like putting a letter in an envelope which goes in a box which goes on a truck and maybe then the box is transferred to/from a plane or a bigger truck the goal being to get the piece of paper to someone using whatever transport materials and equipment required.

yes internet, to isp to cable to modem to ethernet in your house (AKA LAN), to some device in your house, printer, computer, etc.  then the reverse is device in house to lan to modem to isp to internet, handwaving over some steps.  with wireless ingress can be modem/router/wifi (in one box) to laptop/phone/device and then back wireless from device to modem/router/access point. Or could be modem to router ethernet, router to wireless access point, wired ethernet, then wireless to phone/laptop/device and then the reverse to go back.  for wired ethernet and fiber there are directional connections, for the cable connection clearly there isnt, somehow the signals have to go both ways (different frequencies).